# Is there a way to use a for loop to create directories based on filenames?

Tags: linux, for-loop, mkdir

I want to create directories based on names of files I already have. For example, let's say I have:

`red.txt green.txt blue.txt purple.txt orange.txt`

Would there be a way to create directories called:

`red/ green/ blue/ purple/ orange/` ?

I tried doing:

`for f in *.txt; do mkdir {$f}; done`

`for f in *.txt; do mkdir {$f}.txt; done`

`for f in *.txt; do mkdir "$f/"; done`

etc etc, variations thereof. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What happened with your own attempts?

Comment: `for f in *.txt; do mkdir {$f}; done` gave me the result of directories called `{blue.txt} {green.txt} {orange.txt} {purple.txt} {red.txt}`

Comment: `for f in *.txt; do mkdir {$f}.txt; done` gave me the same thing, except that the directories in this case were called `{blue.txt}.txt {green.txt}.txt {orange.txt}.txt {purple.txt}.txt {red.txt}.txt`

Comment: and `for f in *.txt; do mkdir "$f/"; done` just gave me an error message, saying "this file already exists" for each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *bash-only* way of going about it ...

```
for f in *txt; do mkdir ${f%.*}; done
```

We employ bash's [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) here, in case you're curious.

Comment: This does exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you!